# ShellExecute not working in switch statement

Tags: mfc

I've been trying to make an MFC Dialog that runs a batch script when a button called 'Render' is pressed, and a different batch script runs if the user selects a different option via radio buttons:

[image: Dialog view --> user inputs options via radio buttons which changes output when 'Render' is clicked]

I wrote a switch statement:

```
    UpdateData(TRUE);
switch (render_speed) {
case 0: 
    ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), _T("cmd.exe"), _T("/C testing.cmd"), _T("C:\\Users\\pranav\\manim"), SW_SHOW);
    break;
case 1: 
    ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), _T("cmd.exe"), _T("/C testing_two.cmd"), _T("C:\\Users\\pranav\\manim"), SW_SHOW);
    break;
}
```

(render_speed is the variable for the group Render Options)

Case 0 in the switch statement works, but Case 1 does not (it opens and closes in a fraction on seconds). I have checked to make sure that all the batch scripts are working. I have also tried using an if statement instead.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `it opens and closes in a fraction on seconds` That means `ShellExecute` itself works. Replace `/c` with `/k` to keep the cmd prompt open and see what happened.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks for your help. This almost works! I have to put the contents of my batch script into the quotes though or I get 'testing_two.cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Do you mean to have missing `break;` statements for each `case`?

Comment: No, it was a silly mistake. I'll change my code now